# Photoshop Smart-object placing larger then original image

Tags: graphics, 2d, photoshop

Calling all Photoshop users!! please help me work out this issue. i have decided to break up all of my player components / game assets into smart objects to take advantage of all the benefits that come with this functionality. however i have noticed something strange that can be seen in the below example.

When i create a smart object i can see that the object is created with its original object size, however when i add that object to another scene its size randomly increases and i dont know why.

[image: image showing smart object auto resizing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Photoshop General preferences uncheck `Resize Image During Place` — with this option enabled importing SOs from the Library resizes them to document size.

Also [Graphic Design Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to ask questions like this than Stack Overflow because it has nothing to do with coding.